# Javascript: How can I display the total price for the values that are inputted into it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, django-templates

I am creating a project that will serve as a grocery store. The customer will click on the checkboxes and then click a submit button, prompting an alert to show the values that were clicked and the total price.

home.html

```
    <form action="{% url 'js' %}" method="POST" id="menuForm">
      {% for post in posts %}
        {% if post.quantity > 0 %}
            <article class="media content-section">
              <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                  <a class="mr-2">{{ post.category }}</a>
                </div>
                <h2><a class="article-title" >{{ post.title }}</a></h2>
                <p class="article-content"> Price: ${{ post.Price }}</p>
                <p class="article-content"> Sale: ${{ post.Sale }}</p>
                <input type="checkbox" id="product_{{ post.id }}" value="{{ post.title }}" form="menuForm" name="products" > Inventory count: {{ post.quantity }}
              </input>
              </div>
            </article>
        {% else %}
        {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
      <button id="btn" type="submit" form="menuForm">Confirm Purchase</button>
    </form>
<script src="{% static "JS/javascript.js" %}" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

javascript.js

```
function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {  
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
    let values = [];
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    });
    return [values];
    console.log(getSelectedCheckboxValues('products'))
}

console.log(values)
var price = 0;
var tPrice = 0;
for (var i = 0;i<values.length;i++){
    if (values[i] == 'Milk'){
        var MPrice = 3.99
        tPrice = price+MPrice;
    }
    if (values[i] == 'Cheese'){
        var CPrice = 4.50
        tPrice = price + CPrice;
    }
    if (values[i] == 'Yogurt'){
        var YPrice = 1.99
        tPrice = price + YPrice;
        }
console.log(values[i])
}

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    alert('You ordered: ' + getSelectedCheckboxValues('products')+
        '\nTotal Price: $' + tPrice );
});
```

My issue at the moment is that the alert only shows the values that are chosen. However, it does not print the total price. If anyone can help me with this I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Please post relevant code example in form of simple HTML, CSS & JS. Eliminate django code

Comment: My project is built in Django so it would not be possible for me to post the code after removing the Django portions of it. I apologize if that makes it more confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make some changes to your script.

- your `values` variable is declared within `getSelectedCheckboxValues` function, so you cannot access that variable out of the function.

So simply move everything to your `getSelectedCheckboxValues` function and return an object which contains `values` `tPrice`

```
function getSelectedCheckboxValues(name) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(`input[name="${name}"]:checked`);
    let values = [];
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        values.push(checkbox.value);
    });

    var price = 0;
    var tPrice = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        if (values[i] == 'Milk') {
            var MPrice = 3.99
            tPrice += price + MPrice;
        }
        if (values[i] == 'Cheese') {
            var CPrice = 4.50
            tPrice += price + CPrice;
        }
        if (values[i] == 'Yogurt') {
            var YPrice = 1.99
            tPrice += price + YPrice;
        }
        console.log(values[i])
    }

    return {values, tPrice};
}

const btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const result = getSelectedCheckboxValues('products');
    alert('You ordered: ' + result.values +
        '\nTotal Price: $' + result.tPrice);
});
```